# Resolving dependencies using "global.json" projects property

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

Working on an **Asp.Net Core** project and using "**global.json**" to pull in external dependencies, seemed to work for a while. But lately it stopped working. The external library does not get pulled into the solution explorer view.

In my effort to figure out what is going on, I setup a trivial example. 
Below are the various files and procedures I used:

> The Project named is **MyProject**.

The **sdk version** used is shown below:

```
~\MyProject> dotnet --info
  .NET Command Line Tools (1.0.0-preview2-1-003177)
  Product Information:
   Version:            1.0.0-preview2-1-003177
   Commit SHA-1 hash:  a2df9c2576
  Runtime Environment:
   OS Name:     Windows
   OS Version:  10.0.14393
   OS Platform: Windows
   RID:         win10-x64*
```

The "MyProject's" **solution explorer view**:

```
Solution 'MyProject' (1 project)
   Solution Items
  global.json
   src
      MyProject
        Properties
        References
        Program.cs
        project.json
```

The project's **program.cs** source code:

```
namespace MyProject
{
   public class Program
   {
       public static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           var Var1 = new MyLib();
           Console.WriteLine($"{Var1.VariableOne}");
       }
   }
```

}

The **project.json** file:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
   "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.0.1"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

The **global.json** file:

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "../MyLibrary/src" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-1-003177"
  }
}
```

> The **Library** project is named: **MyLibrary**

The version of **sdk** used:

```
~\MyLibrary\src\MyLibrary>dotnet --info

.NET Command Line Tools (1.0.0-preview2-1-003177)

Product Information:
 Version:            1.0.0-preview2-1-003177
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  a2df9c2576

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.14393
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
```

The "MyLibrary" **solution explorer view**:

```
Solution 'MyLibrary' (1 project)
 > Solution Items
    > global.json
 > src
    > MyLibray
        > Properties
        > References
        > Class1.cs
        > project.json
```

The "MyLibrary" **class.cs** code:

```
namespace MyLibrary
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public string VariableOne { get; set; } = "MessageOne";
        public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The "MyLibrary" **global.json** file is:

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-1-003177"
  }
}
```

> The steps followed for **packaging** the library in the command line:

```
 > cd src\MyLibrary
 > dotnet pack
```

And below is the result of packaging:

```
~\MyLibrary\src\MyLibrary\bin\Debug>dir
12/14/2016  06:33 PM             2,926 MyLibrary.1.0.0.nupkg
12/14/2016  06:33 PM             5,264 MyLibrary.1.0.0.symbols.nupkg
12/14/2016  06:22 PM    <DIR>          netstandard1.6
```

Given all the above, which before I managed to get working, now, when I try to restore the references for "MyProject", the "MyLibrary" package does not get picked up. The Solution explorer remains the same as per before ( and of course the "Class1" reference remains unresolved).

I forgot to mention that I am using VS 2015 community.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK, just figure out what I was missing.
In the project.json file of MyProject, I needed to add the following dependency:

```
"MyLibrary": {
    "target": "Project",
    "version": "*"
    }
```